# How to solve this error "Warning:Attempt to present whose view is not in the window hirearchy"?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm developing an iOS application but I don't have storyboard and I do pure swift code, when I try to check the authentication in the MainViewController and I use **perform** to go to another ViewController and if token doesn't exist show button in MainViewController I ran into this warning and it won't work.

when I use **perform** like the snippet below to go to another ViewController by clicking on a button it works just fine.

I've seen all the answer by the title I'm asking here but all the examples has storyboards so it's not related to my question here.

here's a snippet that I'm trying to do in my app.

```
if defaults.string(forKey: Constants().userTokenKey) != nil
            && defaults.string(forKey: Constants().userTokenKey) != ""  {
            print("YOU ARE IN ELSE!")
            let vc = SelectLocationOnMapViewController()
            UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.loginRegisterParentView.alpha = 1.0
            })
            setButtonActions()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

it seems you use the rootVC which isn't yet fully presented to present another Vc , you need to move this code from `viewDidLoad` to say `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear`